# Why does Flask-RESTful' add_resource() has a parameter for URLs and another one for endpoints?

Tags: python, flask, api-design, endpoint, flask-restful

I'm developing an API using Flask and the Flask-RESTful extension. I'm creating my endpoints and resources, but I'm confused with the difference between the resource "url" and its "endpoint". To my understanding, the URL itself *is* the endpoint. I was also reading the [answers to this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580562/what-is-the-difference-between-resource-and-endpoint) and they also suggest that an URL is an endpoint.

Yet [the Flask-RESTful docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.Api.add_resource) mentions that the `add_resource` method has an argument for URLs and it can *also* receive an endpoint name. They even provide this example:

```py
api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/', '/hello')
api.add_resource(Foo, '/foo', endpoint="foo")
api.add_resource(FooSpecial, '/special/foo', endpoint="foo")
```

In which I understand what they are doing, but again I don't understand what the endpoint name does.

What is the difference between the URL and the endpoint name? And why would I set an endpoint name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_resource#flask_restful.Api.add_resource):

**URL**

> one or more url routes to match for the resource, standard flask
> routing rules apply. Any url variables will be passed to the resource
> method as args.

**ENDPOINT**

> endpoint name (defaults to Resource.**name**.lower() Can be used to
> reference this route in fields.Url fields

The **endpoint** parameter must be specified when you intend to manage two or more urls with the same class, in fact, considering the following code snippet:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
    
    
class my_handler(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return request.base_url
        
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
        
api.add_resource(my_handler, '/')
api.add_resource(my_handler, '/hello')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

flask will not be able to execute the application, raising the exception:

```
Exception has occurred: AssertionError       
View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: my_handler
```

In order for flask to handle multiple urls with the same class, you will need to specify the endpoint parameter:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource


class my_handler(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return request.base_url

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(my_handler, '/', endpoint='/')
api.add_resource(my_handler, '/hello', endpoint='/hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

By making an http call, the server responds by returning the url of the requested resource:

```
curl --location --request GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
```

```
curl --location --request GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello"
```